# Pandas df.loc indexing with multiple conditions and retrieving value

Tags: python, pandas

I can't understand this example in the documentation for version 1.1.4

```
In [45]: df1
Out[45]: 
          A         B         C         D
a  0.132003 -0.827317 -0.076467 -1.187678
b  1.130127 -1.436737 -1.413681  1.607920
c  1.024180  0.569605  0.875906 -2.211372
d  0.974466 -2.006747 -0.410001 -0.078638
e  0.545952 -1.219217 -1.226825  0.769804
f -1.281247 -0.727707 -0.121306 -0.097883
```

Then it slices it using labels

```
In [50]: df1.loc[:, df1.loc['a'] > 0]
Out[50]: 
          A
a  0.132003
b  1.130127
c  1.024180
d  0.974466
e  0.545952
f -1.281247
```

But the value at index 'f' is less than zero.

And the condition is on index 'a' so why is it returning the entire first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us look at the below specific piece of code first. So when you do,

```
df.loc['a']>0
```

This picks all the values of `index` 'a' which satisfies this condition.In this case, only column A's value corresponding to index 'a' is greater than 0.

Output:

```
A     True
B    False
C    False
D    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Now with this command `df.loc[:,df.loc['a']>0`, what you are essentially doing is below,

```
df.loc['a':'f',[True,False,False,False]]
```

You are asking here to pick the first column of the df for all indexes. In your df, you are asking for just column 'A' here, so it prints.

```
    A
a   0.132003
b   1.130127
c   1.024180
d   0.974466
e   0.545952
f   -1.281247
```

Look at the [pandas loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for details on how `df.loc` works